# How to compare only .c and .h files of two folders in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have two project folders. I want to compare their contents. One folder has some makefile, configuration files, binary, executables and source files.

Source file consists of .c and .h files.

I want to compare contents of both folders but I only want compare source files (i.e. *.c and *.h files within the folders). How do I do that?

If I use <kbd>Compare With</kbd> > <kbd>Each Other</kbd> option, it shows all the differences.

Comment: do you mean "I want to compare contents of both **folders**"?

Comment: yes but only .c and .h files within those folders.

Comment: thanks alex, your suggested correction are helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse Mars, There's a `Preferences > General > Compare/Patch > Filtered Members` field in the Preferences Dialog. You can specify file extensions to exclude (filter out) files other than `*.c` and `*.h`. Though I didn't check the other version of Eclipse, I think there's similar option to do this.

Comment: tested on Spring Tool Suite (Eclipse Luna) and it works

Comment: Yes, Its working. its a good to exclude all other entries. Is there any way to include also ?